# MCU on custom PCB suddenly stop working

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

After nearly two weeks of testing, STM32L MCU suddenly stopped working.
It is not recognized by ST-LINKv2 debugger (tried connecting using stlink under Linux and STM's ST-LINK utility under Windows).

MCU power is OK, ground and SWD pins are connected.

- I did not do anything special with device when it suddenly stopped working
- software does not redefine SWD pins
- device is powered from battery, so do not expect that MCU was burned by some voltage spike
- MCU was bought from local reseller that seems to have original parts (but not sure)
- although present on schematic, quartz crystal and capacitors are not soldered. Device is driven from internal clock (HSI).

It seems that MCU is dead. The only explanation that come to my mind is EMI.

Please help to understand what could be the source of problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "software does not redefine SWD pins" not intentionally perhaps, but this can still happen with a bad firmware load.  Look at the past questions which discuss connecting SWD with nReset asserted - that usually lets you do an erase and then reprogram.  But also check if the chip is hot or drawing excessive power, either of which would indicate electrical damage.

Comment: If it's not a bad firmware load I wouldn't suspect EMI but ESD damage would be more likely.

Comment: also, the good ol' mechanical problems should be ruled out, too: cold solder joints becoming non-contacts due to time, vibrations, temperature, capacitors breaking, particles shorting pins, that kind of fun

Comment: You could try the usual things we do when we don't have a clue. Try flexing the board in different directions. Hit it with freezer spray.

Comment: What's the history? ...2 weeks of what? 2 weeks of man-handling or two weeks of being in a box wired up and working... If its door #1, it's likely ESD, if it's door #2 and all the inputs and outputs are in spec, it may just be an early life failure.

Comment: @Chris RESET was pulled low during reflashing. Chip temperature is normal. Will also check current consumption.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can keep reset low the whole time, either.  Rather, you do the initial part of connection with it low, then release it.

Comment: @Trevor 2 weeks of man-handling without using a case.
Got your point

Comment: @ChrisStratton it was my bad. Instead of NRST I've connected TRST (pin 3 on STLINKv2 connector).
After using NRST pin and setting "Connect after Reset" option in ST-LINK utility I was finally able to connect to MCU.

Comment: @ChrisStratton can you post your answers so that I can accept it? Or let me know if I should close this one as duplicate.
BTW, could you please elaborate on "still happen with a bad firmware load". How could such happen?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming batt/MCP73831 is 4.2v, the [TPS7361](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps736.pdf)'s R9 and R4 produce an output of 3.0v so this is Vdd. If PWR_OFF were an output (either state) while S1 were closed, even for an instant - that is a direct path back to the battery (4.2v, 1.2v more than Vdd.)

**Edit**: The [STM32L152RBT6](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/66/71/4b/23/94/c3/42/c8/CD00277537.pdf/files/CD00277537.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00277537.pdf) does have many 5v-tolerable inputs (and no \$V_{DDIO}\$ pin to limit this), of which PB12 (pin 33) is one. So what must have happened is, the button was pressed while the micro was asserting an output on this pin, then more current than was allowable flowed into the device (from a pin higher than Vdd.)

Section 6.2, table 11, Absolute maximum current ratings, shows \$I_{INJ(PIN)}\$ is limited to -5/+0mA. My guess is that pressing the button while the output was asserted happened, and the chip failed from an over-current condition.

I'd use a mosfet or BJT to pull EN low instead of pulling the line directly from an output. As @Chris says in the comments, it may be possible to cut a trace and splice in an alteration, but this part of the circuit needs some more thought.

Comment: Nice catch ....

Comment: It would appear that the mistake may be in connecting the PWR_OFF signal to the MCU *at all*.  Perhaps that was added to an existing design that used the sensible path through the diode from MCU_PWR_EN in an attempt to provide a force-off that could override the switch, if so, that needs to be re-thought.  Possibly something as simple as a series resistor that would form a divider with the existing pull-down would keep the voltage in a safe range, or at least limit the current through the protection diode.

Comment: Cutting the PWR_OFF trace, making D3 a resistor and D1 0-ohm, then using MCU_PWR_EN for both purposes could perhaps salvage the existing PCB, though it's not really clear why overriding the switch is necessary.  Another approach sometimes used is a series capacitor for the turn-on path, and the MCU then either starts sustaining the enable, or if the program or brownout detector decides the cell voltage is too low, lets it drop; the capacitor means it can only keep draining the cell if pressed and released, not merely held on by being jammed into a backpack.

Comment: @rdtsc PWR_OFF is connected to five volt tolerant pin. Does 4.2V can hurt?

Comment: @ChrisStratton exactly, PWR_OFF was added later in order to implement software power off of device.
Adding resistors instead of diodes wont help to distinguish when button was pressed to power off the device.

Comment: @rostokus, I found the datasheet for this LQFP64 device. You're right, it does have 5V tolerable inputs. Answer edited to reflect the changes.